# Is there a way to see whether the icon/button has been hidden for a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

A user can chose to hide the icon for an extension by right clicking the icon and selecting 'Hide button'.

Is there any way to determine whether the button has been hidden so the user experience can be adapted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way of doing it.

Neither the directly applicable API, `browserAction`, nor the only other API that could give this information, `management`, have any direct way of querying it.

Unless there is some non-trivial quirk (read: bug/undefined behavior) you can detect, you can't get notified of this.